# Error 1084: Expecting righparen before release

Tags: flash-cs3

My code is:

(on release) {gotoAndPlay('amarula_main')}

Then I get the following:

1084: Syntax error:expecting rightparen before release.

I get two error messages like that, both with the same error, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should be:

on (release) {gotoAndPlay('amarula_main')}

Does that work?